# (PHP) Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()

Tags: linux, php, php.ini

I have recently updated my server to the latest version of PHP 5.1.27, except now - a few of the scripts 
used by my websites come up with the following error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagettftext()

I did build the latest version with GD and have had a look at various answers on the internet - but nothing
seems to work for me.

I have cPanel/WHM 11.30.4 on a Cent OS 5 Linux server.

I'd appreciate some help with this :-)

Comment: Admin panels are [off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) (see [this](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258) for some reasons). The community has decided that we want to close both old and new questions when such an admin panel is relevant ([link 1](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8086), [link 2](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have freetype? The imagegettftext() function relies on both GD and freetype. If you're missing one of the 2, the function won't be defined.

Comment: So I need to tick "TTF (FreeType)" (as it wasn't ticked) and hit build again? :-)

Comment: Yeah, try that.